# XMLHttpRequest don't send to another page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I use this code to upload files, and this code have a progressbar. The problem with this code is that it never send me to "upload.php" after it have uploaded the file, after it reach 100% on the progressbar. (It's not my code).

The code:

```
// get form data for POSTing
//var vFD = document.getElementById('upload_form').getFormData(); // for FF3
var vFD = new FormData(document.getElementById('upload_form')); 

// create XMLHttpRequest object, adding few event listeners, and POSTing our data
var oXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();        
oXHR.upload.addEventListener('progress', uploadProgress, false);
oXHR.addEventListener('load', uploadFinish, false);
oXHR.addEventListener('error', uploadError, false);
oXHR.addEventListener('abort', uploadAbort, false);
oXHR.open('POST', 'upload.php');
oXHR.send(vFD);
```

The whole script

```
// common variables
var iBytesUploaded = 0;
var iBytesTotal = 0;
var iPreviousBytesLoaded = 0;
var iMaxFilesize = 1048576; // 1MB
var oTimer = 0;
var sResultFileSize = '';

var uploadingcanceld = "حدث خطأ أثناء تحميل الملف";


function secondsToTime(secs) { // we will use this function to convert seconds in normal time format
    var hr = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
    var min = Math.floor((secs - (hr * 3600))/60);
    var sec = Math.floor(secs - (hr * 3600) -  (min * 60));

    if (hr < 10) {hr = "0" + hr; }
    if (min < 10) {min = "0" + min;}
    if (sec < 10) {sec = "0" + sec;}
    if (hr) {hr = "00";}
    return hr + ':' + min + ':' + sec;
};

function bytesToSize(bytes) {
    var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB'];
    if (bytes == 0) return 'n/a';
    var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)));
    return (bytes / Math.pow(1024, i)).toFixed(1) + ' ' + sizes[i];
};

function fileSelected() {

    // hide different warnings
    document.getElementById('upload_response').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('error2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('abort').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('warnsize').style.display = 'none';

    // get selected file element
    var oFile = document.getElementById('ufile').files[0];

    // filter for image files
    var rFilter = /^(image\/bmp|image\/gif|image\/jpeg|image\/png|image\/tiff)$/i;
    if (! rFilter.test(oFile.type)) {
        document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'block';
        return;
    }

    // little test for filesize
    if (oFile.size > iMaxFilesize) {
        document.getElementById('warnsize').style.display = 'block';
        return;
    }

    // get preview element
    var oImage = document.getElementById('preview');

    // prepare HTML5 FileReader
    var oReader = new FileReader();
        oReader.onload = function(e){

        // e.target.result contains the DataURL which we will use as a source of the image
        oImage.src = e.target.result;

        oImage.onload = function () { // binding onload event

            // we are going to display some custom image information here
            sResultFileSize = bytesToSize(oFile.size);
            document.getElementById('fileinfo').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('filename').innerHTML = 'Name: ' + oFile.name;
            document.getElementById('filesize').innerHTML = 'Size: ' + sResultFileSize;
            document.getElementById('filetype').innerHTML = 'Type: ' + oFile.type;
            document.getElementById('filedim').innerHTML = 'Dimension: ' + oImage.naturalWidth + ' x ' + oImage.naturalHeight;
        };
    };

    // read selected file as DataURL
    oReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
}

function startUploading() {
    // cleanup all temp states
    iPreviousBytesLoaded = 0;
    $("#upload").animate({height:'75px'},350);
    $("#loadingborders").fadeIn(1500);
    $("#progress_percent").fadeIn(1500);
    $("#upload_button").fadeOut(100);
    $("#ufile").fadeOut(100);
    document.getElementById('ufile').style.margin = '5px 0px -5px 0px';
    document.getElementById('upload_response').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('error2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('abort').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('warnsize').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('progress_percent').innerHTML = '';
    var oProgress = document.getElementById('progress');
    oProgress.style.display = 'block';
    oProgress.style.width = '0px';

    // get form data for POSTing
    //var vFD = document.getElementById('upload_form').getFormData(); // for FF3
    var vFD = new FormData(document.getElementById('upload_form')); 

    // create XMLHttpRequest object, adding few event listeners, and POSTing our data
    var oXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();        
    oXHR.upload.addEventListener('progress', uploadProgress, false);
    oXHR.addEventListener('load', uploadFinish, false);
    oXHR.addEventListener('error', uploadError, false);
    oXHR.addEventListener('abort', uploadAbort, false);
    oXHR.open('POST', 'upload.php');
    oXHR.send(vFD);

    // set inner timer
    oTimer = setInterval(doInnerUpdates, 300);
}

function doInnerUpdates() { // we will use this function to display upload speed
    var iCB = iBytesUploaded;
    var iDiff = iCB - iPreviousBytesLoaded;

    // if nothing new loaded - exit
    if (iDiff == 0)
        return;

    iPreviousBytesLoaded = iCB;
    iDiff = iDiff * 2;
    var iBytesRem = iBytesTotal - iPreviousBytesLoaded;
    var secondsRemaining = iBytesRem / iDiff;

    // update speed info
    var iSpeed = iDiff.toString() + 'B/s';
    if (iDiff > 1024 * 1024) {
        iSpeed = (Math.round(iDiff * 100/(1024*1024))/100).toString() + 'MB/s';
    } else if (iDiff > 1024) {
        iSpeed =  (Math.round(iDiff * 100/1024)/100).toString() + 'KB/s';
    }

    document.getElementById('speed').innerHTML = iSpeed;
    document.getElementById('remaining').innerHTML = '| ' + secondsToTime(secondsRemaining);        
}

function uploadProgress(e) { // upload process in progress
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
        iBytesUploaded = e.loaded;
        iBytesTotal = e.total;
        var iPercentComplete = Math.round(e.loaded * 100 / e.total);
        var iBytesTransfered = bytesToSize(iBytesUploaded);

        document.getElementById('progress_percent').innerHTML = iPercentComplete.toString() + '%';
        document.getElementById('progress').style.width = (iPercentComplete * 4).toString() + 'px';
        document.getElementById('b_transfered').innerHTML = iBytesTransfered;
        if (iPercentComplete == 100) {
            var oUploadResponse = document.getElementById('upload_response');
            oUploadResponse.innerHTML = '<h1>Please wait...processing</h1>';
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = 'unable to compute';
    }
}

function uploadFinish(e) { // upload successfully finished
    var oUploadResponse = document.getElementById('upload_response');
    oUploadResponse.innerHTML = e.target.responseText;

    document.getElementById('progress_percent').innerHTML = '100%';
    document.getElementById('progress').style.width = '400px';
    document.getElementById('filesize').innerHTML = sResultFileSize;
    document.getElementById('remaining').innerHTML = '| 00:00:00';

    clearInterval(oTimer);
}

function uploadError(e) { // upload error
    $('#errormessage').slideUp('fast', function() {
        $('#errormessage').html(uploadingcanceld);
        $('#errormessage').slideDown('fast');
    });
    clearInterval(oTimer);
}  

function uploadAbort(e) { // upload abort
    clearInterval(oTimer);
}
```

Comment: I would definitely add console printing (console.log) to beginning of each function and watch the developer console (all modern browsers have built-in console). Also look at network packets, you may find out the reason why easily. When I first read your question, I suspected a cross site scripting problem but if the upload succeeds, that should not be the case

Comment: I'm wondering if jQuery could help shorten your code.

Comment: I only get css problem in the console, but there is no report about wrong javascript code

Comment: EWW at the hungarian notation you are using. and FYI, `setInterval` returns an integer, not an object.

Comment: haha ok what is the solution for that?

Comment: How would you expect this code to "send you to upload.php"? It does this in XHR, so you can't see results (if any) in the current page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XHR is a dynamic data call, it's not a document forwarding call, meaning the reason why we have XHR to begin with is so that we DON'T want to forward a client to another page to get new content into the page. So you might want to wait on the XHR to complete the process of sending the data, acquire the results of that transfer via XHR, and based on those results do as you want.

So in essence, you are creating a virtual document client/server transfer and handshake without having to forward the client, that of which is the role XHR was created to fulfill.

Comment: I understod it's logic today after i posted this question, so maybe my question is little bit dumb. Now i have made a handshake and it works, but i have problem with the arabic encoding, when i get the content from the other page i have problem with this line [e.target.responseText;] i get very strange symbols in my html page